# change local variable size

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a big giant sql using a predefined parameter at many places, please see below

```
-- @myVar nvarchar(10)   This was passed as a parameter with some value in it.

@myVar = 'sad' + @myVar
```

Here is a Big giant sql using @myvar at many places

As u guys would have figured out that if the length of value in @myVar is > 7, then addking 'sad' will remove characters from the end of @myVar. A normal solution to this is to declare another local variable of @myVar.len + my required size(3 in this case).But I wanted to know is it possible that I can change the length of @myVar somehow?? Thanks for ur time! :)

Comment: Sorry to be begging the question but do you mean that you have no access to `@myVar` and can't change its definition? Could you let us know what prohibits you from changing the declaration? :)

Comment: @Nonym yeah, I cant change the definition at the first hand, as it is passed to me from some code. Making a change there(in the code from where it is passed) is not an option for me. :( Feel free to clarify any doubts pls

Comment: As far as I know.. If you can't access/change the definition of `@myVar` then that's it :( .. any attempt to re-declare it will generate an error...